# letters won't transform without `inline-block` property

Tags: html, css

Currently working this [project](https://50projects50days.com/projects/form-wave/) but was stuck on the letter transitioning. ([code](https://github.com/bradtraversy/50projects50days/tree/master/form-input-wave)). For simplicity sake I will only have the relevant code for letter effect.

```css
.form-control label span {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: .3s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}
.form-control input:focus + label span,
.form-control input:valid + label span {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
    color: lightblue
}
```

```html
<div class="form-control">
    <input type="text" required>
    <label>
        <span style="transition-delay:0ms;">E</span>
        <span style="transition-delay:50ms;">m</span>
        <span style="transition-delay:100ms;">a</span>
        <span style="transition-delay:150ms;">i</span>
        <span style="transition-delay:200ms;">l</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

My Question is why does the `.form-control label span` need to have the `display: inline-block` property to actually have the letters `transform: translateY(-30px)`? When it the `inline-block` is not present, the letters do not move at all.

Thanks for the help in advance for understanding this.

Comment: gotcha. Sorry for the duplicate question. @yousoumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the default display of a span is inline, so it's not considered as a block.

Also, you can not use the transform property on an inline element, it should be used on a block or inline-block.

Comment: gotcha. Sorry for the duplicate question.